# Expansionary monetary policy in case of Pigou effect

Tags: macroeconomics

Suppose consumption is a function of income as well as real money balance(Pigou Effect) and we have other equations as the standard Keynesian model.

I derived diagrammatically as well as logically that the Shape of the aggregate demand in case of Pigou effect will be flatter than in the normal case.

Now, I have to look at the case which causes the large effect in increasing the output when nominal money supply increases?

I looked at diagrammatically at this so it came out to be the monetary policy is relatively ineffective in case of Pigou effect but logically Aggregate demand increases due to increase in consumption caused by the rise in real money balances 
and also due to rising in investment expenditure caused by fall in rate of interest so output increase more in case of Pigou effect rather than in normal/standard case so it comes out to be relatively more effective.

Where am I wrong?